# in bash, remove the last character from a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following code:

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," 
testval+="_ddd"
echo ${testval}
```

But, I need to get rid of the comma after "**ccc**". It will always be the last character of `${testval}` before I add the "**_ddd**". There could be other commas that need to remain in the string.

But so far I can't find anything that works.

e.g.

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," ; 
testval=${testval} | rev | cut -c 2- | rev ; testval+="_ddd" ; 
echo ${testval}
```

or

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," ; 
testval=${testval} | sed 's/.$//' ; testval+="_ddd" ; 
echo ${testval}
```

both result in:

```
aaa_bbb_ccc,_ddd
```

I also tried:

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," ; 
testval=$(${testval} | rev | cut -c 2- | rev) ; 
testval+="_ddd" ; 
echo ${testval}`
```

and

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," ; 
testval=$(${testval} | sed 's/.$//') ; 
testval+="_ddd" ; 
echo ${testval}
```

both result in:

```
-su: {testval}: command not found**
```

Is there not the equivalent or `rtrim` of some similar function? that simply trims the last *n* characters from a string/variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there not the equivalent or rtrim of some similar function? that simply trims the last n characters from a string/variable

Yes there is:

```
   ${parameter%word}
   ${parameter%%word}
          Remove matching suffix pattern.
```

The `%` form removes the shortest match while the `%%` removes the longest match. The corresponding "ltrim"s are `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter##word}`.

So for example

```
$ testval="aaa_bbb_ccc,"
$ testval=${testval%,}
$ echo ${testval}
aaa_bbb_ccc
```

For your case

```
$ testval="aaa_bbb_ccc,"
$ testval=${testval%,}
$ testval+="_ddd"
$ echo ${testval}
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd
```

You can change `,` to `?` to remove any single character; or use `???` to replace n=3 trailing characters and so on. In bash, `word` can be a KSH-style extended glob pattern if the `extglob` shell option is set.

Answer (score 5):

There's only one comma in your initial string, so you'd be better off doing it in one replace operation than deleting the last character and then adding `_ddd`.  e.g.

```
$ testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," 
$ testval="${testval/%,/_ddd}"
$ echo $testval
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd
```

Because the pattern begins with a `%` bash attempts to match a comma, but **only** if it is at the **end** of the string. Compare the difference between this (and note the  `,` i've used to replace the `_` after `aaa` from your original string):

```
$ testval="aaa,bbb_ccc,"
$ testval="${testval/%,/_ddd}"
$ echo $testval
aaa,bbb_ccc_ddd
```

and this, without the `%`:

```
$ testval="aaa_,bbb_ccc,"
$ testval="${testval/,/_ddd}"
$ echo $testval
aaa__dddbbb_ccc,
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the answer right there in your question.  All you had to do was to add `echo` before ${testval}`

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc," ; testval=$(echo ${testval} | sed 's/.$//') ; testval+="_ddd" ; echo ${testval}
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
testval="aaa_bbb_ccc,"
testval=$(echo $testval| awk '{sub(/.$/,"",$0);print $0"_ddd"}')
```

Resulting output:

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd
```